# Load an OpenTK GameWindow inside a Windows form panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, opentk

I have an application made in C# using OpenTk.

this is in a class called `ViewPort`, and is initialized like this:

```
namespace OpenTK_viewport
{
    class ViewPort : GameWindow
    { 

.....
```

my Program.cs is:

```
 [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

           using (ViewPort main = new ViewPort())
            {
                main.Run(60.0);
           }
        }
```

This works great, and opens the game window. Now, I want to embed this window inside a `UserControl`, so i can load it into a `panel` on an existing `Form`.

For example, in the project, I have:

```
namespace OpenTK_viewport
{
    public partial class Form3dViewport : UserControl
    {
        public Form3dViewport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3dViewport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

I would like to embed the `ViewPort` class inside this UserControl.
I can't find an example of this anywhere. How can i go about this?

EDIT:
I am able to add a `GLControl` to the Form instead of a panel. Can I load the `Viewport` class into this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was looking at it wrong. OpenTK can be run straight inside a Form. As illustrated here:

https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/master/Source/Examples/OpenTK/GLControl/GLControlGameLoop.cs

Comment: Hello I have a WinForms application where I run the OpenTK by by WinForms button click. It opens in its own game window. I couldnt manage to incorporate it into Form. Could you help me with this? I spent days already no luck.